# Exception Posting JSON Request containing base 64 Encoded Binary File using FasterXML/jackson - Truncated Payload JSON String

Tags: java, rest, web-services, xml-parsing, jackson

I am trying to post a base 64 encoded binary file as json using the following logic:

Approach A:

```
    this.mapper = new ObjectMapper(new JsonFactory().enable(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_CONTROL_CHARS));
            final JsonParser parser = mapper.getFactory().createParser(jsonText);

//This next line is failing
            JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(parser);
```

Approach B:

```
//This next line is failing

JsonNode jsonNode = JsonLoader.fromString(jsonText);
```

But, no luck, I am getting:

Unexpected end-of-input: was expecting closing quote for a string value
Exception message: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.JsonEOFException

Below is a cut of the field its failing on:

"base64EncodedFileBinary": "JVBERi0xLjYNJeLjz9MNCjIzIDAgb2JqDTw8L0xpbmVhcml6ZWQgMS9MIDYxMDE2L08gMjUvRSA1NTQ2OC9OIDEvVCA2MDUwOS9IIFsgNTc2IDE4MV0+Pg"

The string is processed when the length is reduced, but when the whole string is submitted to the API, it fails.

The payload is truncated after it exceeds a certain length.

Below is an payload printed out on invoking the API via Postman:

```
{
      "a": {
        "b": ["x"],
        "c": {
          "base64EncodedFileBinary": "x",
          "filename": "hello 749 world",
          "mimeType": ["application/pdf"],
          "hash": [{
            "encoding": "SHA256",
            "hash": "x"
          }]
        },
        "x": [
          {
            "base64EncodedFileBinary": "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
```

The json is getting truncated before it gets to the Json Parser i.e. in the interceptor

```
 import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


    import javax.annotation.Priority;
    import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
    import javax.ws.rs.container.ResourceInfo;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
    import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
    import javax.ws.rs.ext.ReaderInterceptor;
    import javax.ws.rs.ext.ReaderInterceptorContext;
    import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;

    @Priority(value = 10)
    @Provider
    public class RestServerReaderInterceptor implements ReaderInterceptor {
        private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestServerReaderInterceptor.class);

        @Context
        private ResourceInfo resinfo;

        @Override
        public Object aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorContext interceptorContext)
                throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
            InputStream inputStream = interceptorContext.getInputStream();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[inputStream.available()];
            inputStream.read(bytes);
            String requestContent = new String(bytes);
            LOG.info("RestServerReaderInterceptor aroundReadFrom requestContent= "+requestContent);

            try {

// THE JSON IS GETTING TRUNCATED BEFORE GETTING HERE

                if (!resinfo.getResourceMethod().getName().contains("Delete"))
                    new JsonValidator().isJsonValid(requestContent);


            } catch (SchemaValidationFailedException e) {


                throw new WebApplicationException(e);
            }

            LOG.info("RestServerReaderInterceptor aroundReadFrom END ");

            // Need to write back the Input content
            interceptorContext.setInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(requestContent.getBytes()));

            return interceptorContext.proceed();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use a different data format, like multipart, to send the file.

Answer (score 0):

POST Requests can be cut by server or browser, are you sure the whole message is submitted to your json deserializer ?

Comment: You are right, the payload is truncated .. I have updated the question with the truncated json string which was captured in the Json Validator class, which tries processing the json.

Comment: So you have to find out the correct configuration server side (tomcat, apache, etc) to let it go through.

Comment: the domain/configuration/domain.xml has max-post-size  is set to max-post-size="157286400" and the payload size is 79.4 KB.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your code is properly reading the input stream.  You are only issuing a single read call and basing it on the value returned by available.  From the documentation on [InputStream.available()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available())

> It is never correct to use the return value of this method to allocate
>   a buffer intended to hold all data in this stream.

If you have access to commons-io you can replace this code with a simple [IOUtils.toString](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString(java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset))

or you can lookup a simple implementation that usually looks something like

`long count = 0;
  int n;
  while (-1 != (n = input.read(buffer))) {
      count += n;
  }
  return count;`

This example is just for illustrative purposes as it does not do anything with the read data. I highly recommend you pull in commons-io to handle this for you.  If you are really desperate and can't use a library you can always reference their source directly [IOUtils](https://github.com/apache/commons-io/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.java) as their license is very permissive.

Comment: Thanks Deadron, you are right. I used Guava i.e. com.google.guava.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I got this working last night by replacing the :

```
InputStream inputStream = interceptorContext.getInputStream();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[inputStream.available()];
            inputStream.read(bytes);
            String requestContent = new String(bytes);
```

with

```
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(interceptorContext.getInputStream(), com.google.common.base.Charsets.UTF_8);
        String requestContent = com.google.common.io.CharStreams.toString(reader);
```

The inherited code (from my colleague!) was reading, but truncating the json data.